# How do I fix the version after adding Facebook Sharing SDK?

Tags: android, facebook

My application had been working fine. I want the user to share the last activity EdiText displayed text in the app on Facebook. To do so, I followed this tutorial. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/
The topic: Share and Send dialogs. 
I followed the steps:
Added mavenCentral()  to repositories.

Added the below line to dependencies.
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5,6)'

After this, I received the error :
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7:28.0.0'

So, here I changed v7 to v4
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

After this step's rebuilding, there were no errors.

I ran the app, but the app shows "App not responding, Close or Wait"

I tried it again, but the app looks froze then closes itself.

The below code is build.gradle : Module app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {

    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.dumdum.newapp"

        minSdkVersion 27

        targetSdkVersion 28

        versionCode 1

        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

    }

}


dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5,6)'

}
```

I want to remove the error here.
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7:28.0.0'

Althought I changed it to
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

Still, the same error exists.

The eventlog is error-free.

But when clicked on this below line, the error box is shown next to it:

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7:28.0.0'
```

OR

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

I could not add error box because Stackoverflow considering that part as spam.

Comment: May be long-running process in main thread. so add your launcher class

Comment: No. Process is not taking time.